# Conditional methods based on reference assembly version in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a project where a reference is going to be updated. Now the new reference has some API that the existing one doesn't have. And this reference is also not entirely backwards compatible with the existing reference. So I want my project to compile certain methods in a class using the [Conditional] attribute based on the reference that has been included in the build. Is it possible to do this in C#, if so how can I do this at compile time?

Comment: You'll have to set the conditionals manually at build.  in VS this is done in the project properties (Build/Conditional symbols).  If you have some custom build steps that choose certain references you'll have to do it in the MS Build step.  Otherwise, there's nothing that will automatically generate conditional compilation symbols soley based on references.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If anyone else can provide a better solution I would gladly accept it. the problem that I will have to face with this solution is that I would have to manually modify the csproj file everytime I add a reference.